Proof that the Dual Transformation of a Dual Transformation is Itself
Let $A$ be an invertible linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then, we know that $A$ takes $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ hyperplanes in its domain to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ hyperplanes in its image. For example, if $n=2$, for some line $L$ in the 2D domain of $A$, the image of every vector along $L$ under transformation by $A$ would be another line in the 2D codomain of $A$.
For every $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ hyperplane in $A$'s domain, let the dual vector $\mathbf{v}_L$ of this hyperplane be the vector perpendicular to this hyperplane, with length equal to $1/d_L$, where $d_L$ is the distance from the origin to the hyperplane. In this manner, $\mathbf{v}_L \cdot \mathbf{l} = 1$ for any $\mathbf{l} \in L$.
I'd like to prove two things:

There is a linear transformation $B$ (we'll call it the dual transformation) that takes dual vectors in the domain of $A$ to dual vectors in the image of $A$. That is, when $A$ takes $L$ to $L'$, $B$ takes $\mathbf{v}_L$ to $\mathbf{v}_{L'}$.
The dual transformation of $B$ is $A$.

~ ~ ~
I came across this problem while trying to visualize the geometric meaning of the transpose without using the matrix definition (i.e. that $A^T$ is $A$ in matrix form reflected over the diagonal). So it turns out that $B$ is simply equal to ${A^T}^{-1}$ which we can prove by a sequence of dot product manipulations, but this doesn't feel very satisfactory as a proof to me.
I feel like this property is quite basic: that if $A$ takes hyperplanes to hyperplanes, and $B$ takes dual vectors to dual vectors, then if we invert the relationship and let $B$ takes hyperplanes to hyperplanes, then $A$ would take $B$'s dual vectors to dual vectors. I'd appreciate any insight or intuition. Thank you!

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$Let $V = \R^n$. A covector $\omega\in V^*$ is a weighted, oriented hyperplane in the sense that $\ker\omega$ is a hyperplane, $\alpha\omega$ for any positive scalar $\alpha$ represents the same hyperplane, and $-\omega$ also represents the same hyperplane.
The map on hyperplanes induced by $A$ that you describe is precisely $\omega \mapsto \omega\circ A^{-1}$. This is easy to see, since if $\omega(v) = 0$ then $A(v)$ is mapped to $(\omega\circ A^{-1})(A(v)) = \omega(v) = 0$. Another way to denote this map is $(A^{-1})^*$, reminiscent of your inverse transpose.
Now, the inner product gives us an isomorphism $\flat : V \cong V^*$, $v \mapsto v^\flat$ where $v^\flat(w) = v\cdot w$. This is precisely the map from a weighted, oriented line $v$ to it's weighted, oriented orthogonal complement hyperplane $v^\flat$. The inverse is denoved $\omega \mapsto \omega^\sharp$.
To get your dual map all we need to do is apply this orthogonalization:
$$
 　B(v) = [(A^{-1})^*(v^\flat)]^\sharp = [v^\flat\circ A^{-1}]^\sharp.
$$
Every step of this is geometric:

Give a vector $v$, we apply $\flat$ to get its orthogonal hyperplane $v^\flat$.
Then, we take the image of this hyperplane under $A$ by applying $(A^{-1})^*$, yielding $v^\flat\circ A^{-1}$.
Finally, we take the orthogonal complement of this hyperplane using $\sharp$, yielding the above formula for $B(v)$.

When we dot with arbitrary $w$ we get
$$
  B(v)\cdot w = v^\flat(A^{-1}(w)) = v\cdot A^{-1}(w).
$$
Thus $B$ is the adjoint of $A^{-1}$ under the standard inner product; such an adjoint is precisely the transpose:
$$
  w^TBv = B(v)\cdot w = [A^{-1}w]^Tv = w^T[A^{-1}]^Tv.
$$

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. For each $x \in X$ and $\xi \in X^*$, denote
$$ \langle \xi,x\rangle = \langle x,\xi\rangle = \xi(x). $$
Recall that $X^{**}=X$.
If $L_1, L_2: X \rightarrow Y$ are linear maps, then $L_1 = L_2$ if and only if for any $x \in X$ and $\eta \in Y^*$,
$$
\langle \eta, L_1 x\rangle = \langle\eta,L_2x\rangle.
$$
Since for any $x \in X$ and $\eta \in Y$,
$$\langle Lx,\eta\rangle = \langle x,L^*\eta\rangle, $$
it follows that for any $x \in X$ and $\eta \in Y^*$,
$$
\langle \eta, L^{**}x\rangle = \langle \eta, (L^*)^* x\rangle = \langle L^* \eta, x\rangle = \langle x,L^*\eta\rangle = \langle Lx, \eta\rangle = \langle \eta, Lx\rangle.
$$
Therefore, $L^{**} = L$.
